# What tasks are F# most suitable for?

Tags: f#

I've read a lot about F# and seen sample code of some of the nice features, like piping.

For a random business application, what modules would be best suitable for being programmed in F#, or would benefit the most in readability/clearness?

Comment: This is somewhat answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159356/why-is-f-so-special and http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!1859.entry

Comment: that first link is broken

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many questions like this already. See for example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328329/why-should-i-use-f
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47315/f-real-world-apps
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179332/anyone-actually-using-f-in-production
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492/where-can-f-actually-save-time-and-money

(Marked this as community wiki, so that others can add other relevant links)

Comment: 3/4 of those links are broken